# pyodbc returns SQL Server DATE fields as strings

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to query a SQL Server 2008 database table with columns of DATE type.

The resulting rows of data contain date strings rather than python datetime.date or datetime.datetime instances.

**This only appears to be an issue for columns of type DATE; columns of type DATETIME are handled correctly and return a datetime.datetime instance.**

### Example

```
import pyodbc
from pprint import pformat
db = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=scratch;Trusted_Connection=yes")
print pformat(db.cursor().execute("select * from Contract").description)
```

Results:

```
(('id', <type 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False),
 ('name', <type 'str'>, None, 23, 23, 0, False),
 ('some_date', <type 'unicode'>, None, 10, 10, 0, True),
 ('write_time', <type 'datetime.datetime'>, None, 23, 23, 3, False))
```

Note that the **some_date** column is indicated as type unicode string, however, in the database this column is defined as DATE:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Contract(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
    some_date DATE NULL,
    write_time DATETIME NOT NULL)
```

Is this normal, and how can I best correct it?

Comment: I have just tried it in Python 2.6 with pyodbc and MSSQL 2008 - it gives me a datetime object.

Comment: @Artsiom Is your column of type DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: @Artsiom Yes, this problem seems to only affect DATE columns.

Comment: I can't check this with DATE column but http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/DataTypes tells that all should be ok. Anyway you can try to use datetime.strptime method to convert string to datetime object if needed.

Comment: I am also getting this issue. Again, specifically with DATE, not DATETIME.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the SQL Server native client. e.g. Put **Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}** in your connection string,instead of 
**DRIVER={SQL Server}**.

Reproduced your scenario with date being returned as string using SQL Server ODBC driver. When using a 2008+ compatible version of the SQL Server native client, the date type is returned as expected, but it looks like datetime2 gets returned as string (in my limited testing).

Table definition:

```
create table dbo.datetest (
    [date] date not null,
    [datetime] datetime not null,
    [datetime2] datetime2 not null
);

insert into
    dbo.datetest
values
    (CAST(current_timestamp as DATE),
     CAST(current_timestamp as datetime),
     CAST(current_timestamp as datetime2));
```

Example:

```
import pyodbc
from pprint import pformat
db = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                    server='TESTSRVR', database='TESTDB',
                    trusted_connection='yes')
print pformat(db.cursor().execute("select * from dbo.datetest").description)
```

Results:

```
(('date', <type 'datetime.date'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False),
 ('datetime', <type 'datetime.datetime'>, None, 23, 23, 3, False),
 ('datetime2', <type 'unicode'>, None, 27, 27, 0, False))
```

Comment: Excellent... now, I just need to work out how to do this under Linux, where I'm using unixODBC and freeTDS... Looks like freeTDS doesn't support anything over SQL 2005: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/tdshistory.htm

Comment: Newer versions of FreeTDS do support date and datetime: FreeTDS 0.95 or newer does (check out https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds)